# TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have the following error in my training loop and I don't really understand what the issue is. I am currently in the process of writing this code so stuff isn't final but I cannot figure out what this problem is.

I have tried googling the error and read some of the answers but still couldn't seem to understand the crux of the issue.

Dataset and Dataloader
(X and Y are already given to me, they are both [2000, 40, 1] tensors)

```py
class TrainingDataset(data.Dataset):
  def __init__(self, X, y):
    self.X = X
    self.y = y

  def __len__(self):
    return Nf
    
  # returns corresponding input/output pairs
  def __getitem__(self, t):
    X = self.X[t]
    y = self.y[t]

    #print(X.shape, y.shape)

    return X, y

# prints torch.Size([2000, 40, 1]) torch.Size([2000, 40, 1])
print(x.size(), y.size())

dataset = TrainingDataset(x,y)
batchSize = 20
dataIter = data.DataLoader(dataset, batchSize)
```

Model:

```py
class Encoder(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, num_inputs = 40, num_outputs = 40):
    super(Encoder, self).__init__()
    
    self.num_inputs = num_inputs
    self.num_hidden = num_hidden
    self.num_outputs = num_outputs

    self.layers = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(num_inputs, num_outputs), 
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(num_outputs, num_outputs),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(num_outputs, num_outputs) 
    )

  def forward(self, x_c, y_c):
    return self.layers(x_c, y_c)
```

Training Loop:

```py
for epoch in range(epochs): 
  for batch in dataIter:
    optimiser.zero_grad()
    l = loss(encoder(x_c=batch[0], y_c=batch[1]), batch[1])
    l.backward()
    optimiser.step()
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-aa1c60616d82> in <module>()
      6   for batch in dataIter:
      7     optimiser.zero_grad()
----> 8     l = loss(encoder(x_c=batch[0], y_c=batch[1]), batch[1])
      9     l.backward()
     10     optimiser.step()

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have just started to learn and do pytorch so I am not good at any of this yet.

Comment: @drum that's the entire error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  def forward(self, x_c, y_c):
    return self.layers(x_c, y_c)
```

Your error lies here, this function should have only 1 argument apart from `self`.

Comment: Is the forward function not allowed to have more than 1 argument?

Comment: tldr: yes
Yes, but actually no. using `encoder(...)` calls the forward with 1 argument, but your forward still exists, no-one uses it

Comment: Hi, so to be clear, calling forward should not be done with multiple arguments? I am running a similar seq2seq model and my decoder takes as input in the forward argument the input, the encoder states as well as the hidden and cell states. This however is throwing the same error as OP